# Elegant Web Permission Schemes

Tags: permissions, binary, flags

I'm currently writing a web application that have about 6-12 pages. On each one of these pages, I want the user to be able to do some (or all) of the following actions: View, Add, Update, and Delete.

The current permission scheme I thought of is having an integer in a database. This integer will correspond to a binary number (e.g.: 26 -> 11010). The resulting binary number acts as a "toggle" and determines what permissions the user has. The definition of what bit represents what permission is stored in another table.

My problem is, if each page has 4 options (view, Add, Edit, Delete), then this way of determining permissions can get out of hand.

Does anyone have any other ideas for a permission scheme that would be as flexible (with respect to configurability) as this, but not as overwhelming (with respect to integer limits)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a better answer, if you really need to go this route, is to have a per-page/per-user row in your database, with a set of permissions, so your table looks like so:

```
 page        user     create read update delete 
 =====       =====    ====== ==== ====== ======
 test.html   joe      y      y    y      n 
 test2.html  joe      n      y    y      n
```

Alternately, as is usually the case, you're better off having roles, like author, editor, reviewer, admin, and giving your roles the fined-grained permissions, and putting the users into roles.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you do not resort to bits. Use separate columns in the DB for each category of permissions and use integers 1 and 0 to indicate whether that permission is granted or not. This would save you from bit manipulations and would be fast as well. The only downside will be a larger number of columns which, by your description, does not seem much of an issue.

Comment: This- it may feel like you're doing a great job at showing off your technical chops by using a bitwise representation for your permissions, and if that is your goal then go for it, but in six months time when you have to go back and revisit that code to fix some problem that has turned up, you'll be wishing you'd gone for the obvious and easily maintained solution.